# Traversing json with javascript - finding children with certain parent values

Tags: javascript, json, xml

JSON:

```
{resources:
    [
    {type:sound, content:0},
    {type:movie, content:1},
    {type:image, content:2},
    ...
]}
```

How do i most effeciently get the content of objects with type=image? can i avoid having to loop through the objects?

Coming from a background working with xml i am used to working with queries inside the getter.

The above sample in xml would let me get the content of the image object by simply writing resources.object(type == "image").content

```
<resources>
    <object type="sound">
        <content>0</content>
    </object>
    <object type="movie">
        <content>1</content>
    </object>
    <object type="image">
        <content>2</content>
    </object>
    ...
</resources>
```

Comment: `data.resources.filter(resource => resource.type === 'image')`? It should also be noted that the JSON you show in your question is not valid as none of the strings are quoted.

Comment: Note that any method you use (including `filter`, `lodash` etc) are all looping "under the hood".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vanilla javascript you can use `filter` to filter them and `map` to get an array of the contents:

```
let json = {resources:
    [
    {type:"sound", content:0},
    {type:"movie", content:1},
    {type:"image", content:2}
]}; 

json.resources.filter( r => r.type === "image" ).map( r => r.content)
```

Comment: This looks perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) for this.

In your case the solution would look like this -

`_.filter(resources, { 'type': 'image' });`